# app()->environment() not using value set by config()

Tags: environment, lumen

I'm writing a unit test for a function that calls `app()->environment()`. The phpunit.xml file sets the environment as `testing`. I want to test the function in other environments as well.

I've tried:

- `config('app.env', 'prod')`
- `config('env', 'prod')`
- `$_ENV['app.env'] = 'prod'`
- `$_ENV['env'] = 'prod'`

I also included the orchestral/testbench package and used this:

```
protected function getEnvironmentSetUp($app)
{
    //Both of the following
    $app['config']->set('app.env', 'prod');
    $app['config']->set('env', 'prod');
}
```

None of these have changed the output of `app()->environment()`.

Am I missing something?

Comment: You've specified both Laravel and Lumen. Which one are you using, and which version? They work differently internally. This sounds like an older Laravel installation or a cached configuration.

Comment: @sisve It's a package for a Lumen 5.5 app. I ran the test from within the package directory. orchestral/testbench is what let me execute `app()->environment()`. I'm not sure where the configuration could have been cached.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up figuring this out by looking at the code for the `->environment()` command. It uses `$this['env']` for the comparison so in my test I wrote:

`app()['env'] = 'prod';`

This seems to be the only way I could get it to work.